# Progress Bar Issue (using onloadstart, onloadend, onloadprogress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

HTML code:

```
<img class="boxImg" src="IMAGE_URL" onloadstart="showProgressBar('#loadBar')" onloadend="hideProgressBar('#loadBar')" />
<div id="loadBar">Loading</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
function showProgressBar(div) { console.log("Load begin"); $(div).fadeIn(50);}
function hideProgressBar(div) { console.log("Load end");   $(div).fadeOut(50);}
```

The image loads fine but the Javascript functions are not called (nothing appears in the console and the div does not have an effect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onloadstart and onloadend supported only audio and video tags - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_loadstart.asp

Comment: This source says otherwise: http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/01/13/html5-image-progress-events/

Comment: w3c - official, truer source

Comment: w3schools has no affiliation with w3c.  In addition, w3schools is notoriously inaccurate.

Comment: If you don't believe w3schools, then do you believe Microsoft? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974159(v=vs.85).aspx. This answer is correct.

Comment: Yes this is correct. The source I found was a proposal, not example of use.

Comment: @maximkou its ok.  I've made the same mistake before.  Just helping to spread knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use `onloadstart` and `onloadend` on the `img` element. These are what are known as [progress events](http://www.w3.org/TR/progress-events/).

Progress events are currently only valid on `video` and `audio` HTML elements. They are not valid on `img` elements.

Comment: I read otherwise on this source from Adobe: http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/01/13/html5-image-progress-events/ . If this is not the case and you are correct, is there an equivalent for images?

Comment: "However, the alternative approach is not yet possible on the web because the HTML image element lacks progress events. The Web Platform team at Adobe is proposing adding image progress events to HTML5 spec and implementing them in browsers. " - http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/01/13/html5-image-progress-events/

Comment: Ah... I see. Thanks for finding that. Shame! Do you know of an equivalent for images?

Comment: No, but Adobe have campaigned to get the spec changed, and it looks like it has been updated. It just isn’t implemented yet. This is the bug tracker for WebKit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=76102