# Can loadstart be used with a button?

Tags: javascript, button, loading, addeventlistener

I am trying to get a button to show a different text when loading... Under MDN I see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onloadstart for an Img.

When searching this in stack I see this but in 2013
[Progress Bar Issue (using onloadstart, onloadend, onloadprogress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885257/progress-bar-issue-using-onloadstart-onloadend-onloadprogress)

So first.. Is this even possible? Then second.. How do I use it properly?

Currently this is what I have

```
this._popupElement.addEventListener("loadstart",() => {
      this._buttonSelector.textContent = "Saving..."
    })
```

Comment: Are you showing progress bar for loading, also is the loading for some api call?

Comment: No progress bar but it is loading for an api call. @AadilMehraj

Comment: Can you place where you do the API call